# Spark on EMR - "Main Class not found." error

Tags: java, apache-spark, emr

I run the following example on EMR -http://www.robertomarchetto.com/spark_java_maven_example

Using -

`aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-<clusterId> --steps Type=Spark,Name="Spark Program",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--class,org.sparkexample.WordCountTask,target/spark-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,<inputPath>, <outputPath>]`

And get the following error -

> "FailureDetails": {
>               "Reason": "Main Class not found.",
>               "LogFile": "s3://some_locatoin/clusterId/steps/stepId/stderr.gz",
>               "Message": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sparkexample.WordCountTask"
>           }

The EMR is of version emr-5.6.0. If you have any idea regarding it, I would love to hear that. Thanks

Update 17/11/2017 - just to make it even more weird, the code runs properly when submitting it to the cluster directly via `spark-submit`

Comment: Is the JAR `target/spark-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` accessible to the EMR?

Comment: Yes. I get the same error even if the jar is in s3. Simpler example from here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/quick-start.html#self-contained-the application works perfectly if the main class is in `src/main/java/` but not if it is deeper.